# Using tag on ListView

Tags: c#, listview, uwp

I am trying to use a tag with my `ListView` Control and I can't seem to get it working.

I add the tag as follows:

```
int ID = 1
foreach(Activity act in ActivityList)
{
    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
    item.Content = "Banana";
    item.Tag = ID
    myListView.Items.Add(item);
}
```

The code above seems to work so far...
Then I want to read the Tag from the `ListViewItem` but nothing seems to work. ex.

```
ListviewItem item = new ListViewItem();
item = myListView.SelectedItem;
```

What am I missing. this gives me an error saying:

> 'Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ListviewItem. an explicit conversion exists(are you missing a cast?)"

What cast am I missing I thought I was placing a `ListViewItem` into a `ListViewItem`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast to `ListViewItem` like this:

```
ListviewItem item = new ListViewItem();
item = (ListViewItem) myListView.SelectedItem;
```